# transforming wordnet txt into lists in python nltk

Tags: python, list, function, nltk

**I am running the following function:**

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

def noun_names(list): 
    for synset in list:
        for lemma in synset.lemmas():
            print lemma.name()

noun_names(list(wn.all_synsets(wn.NOUN)))
```

**and it returns a long list of all the names of nouns in wordnet:**

e.g.

```
epoch
Caliphate
Christian_era
Common_era
day
year_of_grace
Y2K
generation
anniversary
```

How do I take this output, which is neither a string or a list, and turn it into a list? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing to the stdout with your:

```
print lemma.name()
```

Why not append it to a list and return the list?

```
def noun_names(list):
    names = []
    for synset in list:
        for lemma in synset.lemmas():
            names.append(lemma.name())
    return names

names = noun_names(list(wn.all_synsets(wn.NOUN)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I attempted to do this before, but I was forgetting the final line 'return names' which completes the loop. Very helpful!

Comment: No worries -- you should probably also heed Andy's warning -- naming a list "list" in python is generally a dangerous proposition.

Answer (score 0):

It's not returning anything. Your function is *printing*, not returning.

You need to return a list. As a side note, you should rename your function parameter from `list`. You'll clobber something unintentionally with that.

One option is to modify your function slightly to append to a list and then return that:

```
def noun_names(word_list):
    lemma_list = []
    for synset in word_list:
        for lemma in synset.lemmas():
            lemma_list.append(lemma.name())
    return lemma_list
```

Another option is to change the above into a list comprehension:

```
def noun_names(word_list): 
    return [lemma.name() for synset in word_list for lemma in synset.lemmas()]
```

---

Both of these function return a list with the same information. Notice that I removed the `list()` function wrapper around `wn.all_synsets(wn.NOUN)` since the function returns a `list`.

```
lemma_list1 = noun_names(wn.all_synsets(wn.NOUN))
lemma_list2 = noun_names_1(wn.all_synsets(wn.NOUN))
print len(lemma_list1), len(lemma_list2), len(lemma_list1) == len(lemma_list2), lemma_list1 == lemma_list2
```

That final print statement outputs:

```
146347 146347 True True
```

This shows that both lists have the same number of elements (`146347` each and the first `True`) and the lists themselves are equal. A more appropriate test in the code is:

```
assert len(lemma_list1) == len(lemma_list2)
assert lemma_list1 == lemma_list2
```

If the lists aren't the same length or equal the `assert` statement will throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy, both for the advice and for the detailed response. I'm new to NLP and am so pleased to see such a helpful online community.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the list of lemma, check out OMW (Open Multilingual WordNet) http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/

```
$ wget http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/wns/eng.zip
$ unzip eng.zip
$ cut -f3 eng/wn-data-eng.tab | (read;cat)
```